# Help identifying serial communication wiring

Tags: serial

I am wanting to view serial data output from a device on a O-scope. This is a serial measurement board from an industrial robot.

I have managed this in the past with other devices, but I am having no luck here. I get a high signal from SDO pins 8 and 4, but no data.  Even if I get data, how would I clock this to be able to interpret the data?

Any help would be appreciated!

[image: serial measurement board]

Comment: This is going to require a *lot* more detail before responses can be anything more than the sort of random ideas which SE sites are not supposed to be about.   How do you even know that it is supposed to be sending anything?   It may for example only be supposed to answer when given a query.  It would be far more useful if you could watch it in operation while connected to the original equipment.  As for the "clock" it would appear that this would have to be an asynchronous scheme, but first you need to get a waveform so you can start to recognize which one.

Comment: With SDI/SDI-N and SDO/SDO-N, this implies bi-phasic (differential) signalling. Perhaps RS422, 485, etc.  Perhaps 8 data bits, one parity bit, one stop bit, perhaps inverted.  Chris has the right idea - sample across SDI/SDI-N when the machine is powered on and "see" what data is sent to it.  Note may not be able to sample both this way as grounds are connected on oscope.

Comment: I know it has to send data, or it would not really accomplish anything.  As far as this question not falling in line with what SE is about, that was a misunderstanding on my part I suppose.  I am looking for information to help me solve a problem, not a specific solution to my problem.  If I understood everything that was going on here I doubt I would have any questions to ask!  I have tried sampling across SDO/SDO-N without any data, but I will try again.  The mention of "bi phasic" is helpful, maybe I can figure something out looking into that.  Thanks

Comment: I can also add,  I have a "simulated" setup using an original servo/resolver wired to this measurement board.  I do get waveforms from the resolver channels to the board, but my goal is to view the data leaving the board.

Comment: a query may be required on SDI before a response appears on SDO